# How to debug Google app engine Sever Error 500?

Tags: google-app-engine

I deployed a Django web app to GAE, no errors during deployment.
But whenI try to open the website, it shows `Server Error (500)`.

I tried to see some logs using `gcloud app logs read`, it only shows

```
2020-05-28 16:07:48 default[20200528t144758]  [2020-05-28 16:07:48 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2020-05-28 16:07:48 default[20200528t144758]  [2020-05-28 16:07:48 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2020-05-28 16:07:49 default[20200528t144758]  [2020-05-28 16:07:49 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-05-28 16:07:49 default[20200528t144758]  [2020-05-28 16:07:49 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2020-05-28 16:07:49 default[20200528t144758]  [2020-05-28 16:07:49 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2020-05-28 16:07:50 default[20200528t144758]  [2020-05-28 16:07:50 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-05-28 16:08:06 default[20200528t165550]  "GET /" 500
```

The logs are not informative, so I wonder

1) if I could logon to the App Engine machine, and run my web application manually and see what's the error?

2) if not, what are the suggested ways to debug app engine errors?

Comment: Could you clarify if you are using App Engine Flex or Standard environment?

Comment: @Katayoon, I'm using flex.

Answer (score 2):

In App Engine Flex environment, you can [debug your instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance) by enabling the debug mode and SSH to the instance.

You may also [write app logs and structured logs to stdout and stderr](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-application-logs) so that you can look into your application logs and request logs via Logs Viewer or the command line. You may also consider using [Cloud Profiler](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-python#known-issues) which is currently a [free service](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#free-products) to capture profiling data of you application so that you would get a better undrestanding of the characteristics of your application as it runs.

[Cloud Debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs) would also let you inspect the state of your application while running without adding logging statements. Note that Cloud Debugger is currently a free service as well.

Comment: thanks for these links! BTW, can we ssh to the Standard env instances to debug? And is it suggested to use Standard instead of Flex?

Comment: Not unfortunately because in App Engine Standard, application instances run in a sandbox. Choosing App Engine Standard or Flexible depends on your usecase. You may take a look at [this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) comparing these two environments and may help you to choose the environment best meets your needs.

Answer (score 1):

By setting the `DEBUG=1` in Django project settings.py, now I'm able to see error details on GAE.